# сборка проектов Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017

такой вопрос: допустим, я включил какой-либо фреймворк в проект через нугет, но использую из него всего лишь некоторую часть. те компоненты, которые я не использую, студия будет включать в установочные пакеты приложения при сборке ? Просто, возможно, если фреймворк вестит 5 - 8 мегабайт, а использую я из него 2 - 3 десятка классов, не более, есть смысл просто скопировать эти классы в код, не добавляя сам фреймворк, чтобы он место не забирал ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> те компоненты, которые я не использую, студия будет включать в
>   установочные пакеты приложения при сборке?

Да.

> есть смысл просто скопировать эти классы в код, не добавляя сам
>   фреймворк, чтобы он место не забирал ?

Если исходный код доступен и его лицензия позволяет так делать, то можете так сделать. Иначе я бы не советовал.

А вообще вы пытаетесь экономить на спичках.

Comment: то есть особой производительность и размер приложения не пострадают, если я оставлю всё как есть ?

Comment: @Arthur не пострадают.